# Is there a Regular expression to match the html string that can not render any text?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

As the title shows.

```
const reg = //i  //what should the regular expression be?

let HTML = ''; // true

html = '<p></p>' // true
html = '<p> </p>' // true
html = '<p><p></p></p>' // true
html = '<div><br></div>' // true
html = '<div><br/></div>' // true
html = '<div>&nbsp;</div>' // true
html = '<p>a</p><p></p>' // false

reg.test(HTML)
```

Or are there any other methods to match the string like that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Javascript, you could turn the text into a document, then take the document's `textContent`, trim it, and check to see if it's the empty string:

```js
const test = str => new DOMParser()
  .parseFromString(str, 'text/html')
  .documentElement
  .textContent
  .trim() === '';

console.log(test('<p></p>')); // true
console.log(test('<p> </p>')); // true
console.log(test('<p><p></p></p>')); // true
console.log(test('<div><br></div>')); // true
console.log(test('<div><br/></div>')); // true
console.log(test('<div>&nbsp;</div>')); // true
console.log(test('<p>a</p><p></p>')); // false
```

(`DOMParser` is used instead of just assigning the HTML as the `innerHTML` of an element, because the `innerHTML` method can allow for arbitrary code execution, which is unsafe)